# Яке значення та походження слова "каналія"?

Tags: переклад, етимологія

Жодного разу не траплялося мені слово "каналія", аж поки не почав читати твір Джерома Селінджера "Ловець у житі". Наприклад, речення з роману (переклад Олекси Логвиненка):

> Раптом двері відчинились, і в кімнату з розгону влетів **каналія**
>   Стредлейтер.

[СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/kanalija) подає наступне тлумачення:

> Про підступну, хитру людину; шельма, пройдисвіт, шахрай.

Проте в оригіналі автор найчастіше вживає слово "old" (наскільки я розумію, не формально, а значенні "друзяка"). Той самий уривок англійською:

> All of a sudden the door opened, and **old** Stradlater barged in, in a
>   big hurry.

То що найсправді означає "каналія", і звідки походить дане слово?

Comment: невже хтось "В Країні Сонячних Зайчиків" не читав? :)

Comment: @SassaNF це було кілька тисячоліть тому :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Декілька [1](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/canaglia), [2](http://www.wordsense.eu/canaglia/) джерел в Інтернеті вказують що існує італійське слово `canaglia` яке має наступне походження:

> cane + -aglia

`cane` - походить від латинського *[canis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canis)* - тобто [`Собака`](http://sum.in.ua/s/sobaka)

`aglia` - є [італійським суфіксом](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffissi_della_lingua_italiana) який додає *valore collettivo e spregiativo*, тобто узагальнення і принизливість

Тобто таке слово можна використовувати у сенсі [`скотиняки`](http://sum.in.ua/s/skotynjaka), що може підкреслювати ще більш фаміліярне відношення ніж [`друзяка`](http://sum.in.ua/s/druzjaka).

<s>Або ж, наприклад, [Котляревський](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) у своїй [Енеїді](http://ukrlit.org/kotliarevskyi_ivan_petrovych/eneida) досить точно передає сенс слова `каналья` наступними строками характеризуючи латинську богиню [Юнону](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0):</s>

> ...
>   // Но зла Юнона, *суча дочка*,
>   // Розкудкудакалась, як квочка,
>   // Енея не любила — страх;
>   // Давно вона уже хотіла,
>   // Щоб його душка полетіла
>   // К чортам і щоб і дух не пах.
>
> ...

Насправді ж, у ["Altavilla, Sicily: Memories of a Happy Childhood"](https://books.google.pl/books?id=_ap_obJBFJgC&pg=PA124&lpg=PA124&dq=canaglia%20son%20of%20bitch&source=bl&ots=bQ_aqjhsGy&sig=dR39Qm5xjW6iTKsozuKV6SO4G18&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjFtqDv2ZLSAhXD3SwKHcXqDrAQ6AEILjAE#v=onepage&q=canaglia&f=false) Calogero Lombardo<sup>[Sicilian American novelist?](https://sites.google.com/site/dominiccandeloro/home)</sup> роз'яснює особливості вживання:

> People who are beneath contempt are **canaglia**, dogs. Women are not insulted with a word we use here for a female dog. **A female dog is a female dog**.

тобто український найближчий відповідник - це узагальнене, принизливе від [`скот`](http://sum.in.ua/s/skot) - тобто саме [`скотиняки`](http://sum.in.ua/s/skotynjaka)

Comment: Тобто буквально від латини це було б десь так: `собацюра` (в контексті _ах ти ж собацюра ти така_)?

Comment: Що цікаво, перекладач вживає це слово практично у всіх випадках, коли йдеться про "old person". Наприклад, коли головний герой розмовляє з матір'ю свого одногрупника (описує його позитивно), або ж, коли він з любов'ю згадує про свою молодшу сестру.

Comment: наскільки я пам'ятаю (з театральної вистави sic!) там головний герой не дуже любив дідуганів